# Regex Split with Delimiters while keeping delimiters

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I am trying to split a string with delimiters into an array while keeping the delimiters as well.

The string that I have is: "2+37/4+26".

I want the array to be: `[2,+,37,/,4,+,26]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](/q/2206378/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split using lookarounds:

```
String[] tok = input.split("(?<=[+*/-])|(?=[+*/-])");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP3rX3/1)

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[+*/-])  # when preceding character is one of 4 arithmetic operators
|            # regex alternation
(?=[+*/-])   # when following character is one of 4 arithmetic operators
```

Comment: I wish you could explain so I could learn from your **great** answer

Comment: I've added an explanation in answer, also check the demo link and detailed regex description on regex101 also.

Comment: How would you do it if the string also had parenthesis? I tried to escape the parenthesis/brackets but I got an error.

Comment: **parenthesis** was never part of your question so I don't even know the requirements but probably you can use: `String[] tok = input.split("(?<=[()+*/-])|(?=[()+*/-])");`

Comment: <= means preceding and = means follwing ya?

Comment: Yes `(?<=...)` is positive lookbehind and `(?=...)` is positive lookahead